# Spring and Hibernate : How to implement more than 1 POJO in one form

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jstl

I am new to Spring framework.

I have a case I couldn't solve my self. I have two POJO, ie: PersonData and Address. Both of this POJO save on separated table on a database. I mapped both of the POJO to the database tables using Hibernate.

My problem is how to store the POJOs data(PersonData and Address) to relevant tables using one form.

My question is : How to insert data from one form to multiple tables using hibernate?

Comment: Please add more details if you want to get some answers

Comment: It's very much unclear indeed.

Comment: I want to save the data into different tables using one form. How to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Create one object that holds both of the POJOs and set this as your form. For example you could create an object with something like;

```
class PersonFormObejct {
  private PersonData personData;
  private Address address;

  // getters and setters
}
```

Make this your form object rather than either of the two POJOs.

You should be able to access both of the member objects using the notation personFormObject.personData.foo or personFormObject.address.postcode. This is assuming that you named the form object personFormObject of course.

Comment: Thanks for replying. How the insert data works? Does Spring automatically save the POST data to the POJOs?

Comment: Spring will automatically map the form's submitted data onto the POJO yes. Exactly how this works depends on which part of spring you are using. In standard spring you might supply the POJO as the model object in the model and view. In webflow (another part of spring) you would supply the POJO as the model in the flow. Spring then does the mapping for you. For more information on this you need to read the spring documentation which is actually fairly good.